# названия столбцов в SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

Есть сеточный прайс-лист: ширина/высота - пересечение содержит стоимость. Нужно его загнать в БД, так чтобы имена столбцов соответствовали размерам ширины (2000, 2100, 2200 и т.п.). Вопрос в том, как составить sql запрос, чтобы получить данные из столбца с именем соответствующим значению ширины?

```
SELECT 2000 FROM tablename

SELECT '2000' FROM tablename
```

дают не понятный результат в виде списка одинаковых значений равных 2000.
[image: вид таблицы]

[image: запрос и ответ]

Comment: `select width from tablename where width=2000`. Вы имя столбца с его значением не путаете?

Comment: @xdb скорее всего он хотел `select * from tablename where width=2000`

Comment: Первый столбец "height" имеет зачения высот, имена остальных столбцов соответствуют значения ширины, т.е. "2000", "2100", "2200"  и т.д. **SELECT 2000 FROM tablename WHERE height=2100** не выдает никакого результата, хотя должен выдать как раз значение стоимости. Я так понимаю проблема в том, что столбцы имеют имена числами. Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1):

"Escape" название столбцoв, которые могут быть интерпретированы как что-то иное:

```
select height,"2000" from DoorHanRSD02
```

Comment: `select height,"2000" from DoorHanRSD02`  выдает все значения этих двух столбцов, но `select height, "2000" from DoorHanRSD02 where height=2100` не выдает ничего.

Comment: "все значения" - и среди них есть строка, где height=2100? Пора ознакомить нас со структурой таблицы DoorHanRSD02. В частности - с типом поля height.

Comment: таблицу загружал методом импорта из csv файла в программе "DB Browser for sqlite", все поля TEXT. Столбец height имеет значение "2100".

Comment: @ItSilence Попробуйте `WHERE "height" = '2100'`, если у вас там строки.